# How to add two string in a sql query?

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2010

I have a windows form application in which I have a combobox and a text box.
I want to take the value from the text box and store it in a string(eg: txt). And take the value from the combobox and store it in another string(Eg: combo)
I want to run the below query

```
"select * from order where"+combo+"='"+txt+"'";
```

I get the the below error;

> you have an error in your sql syntax check the manual that corresponds
>   to your mysql server version for the right syntax to use
>   near'='Brian'' at line 1

Comment: Try to find something about `SQL Injections`, this may be very dangerous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have no space between `where` and the value from the combo. This should do the trick:

```
"select * from order where "+combo+"='"+txt+"'";
```

Apart from that, don't do this, it opens you up for SQL Injection. You should use a SQLParameter to pass the value.

Comment: While I'm with you on using SQL parameters whenever possible, it is just not possibly to parameterize the column name. I agree with you that it should at least be done for the value.

Comment: thanks... security is not my main concern as its just a simple project for my college assignment... thanks for the tip ...

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a white space after `WHERE` but since I didn't saw any complete answer, I take my chance..

> I have a windows form application in which i have a combo box and a
>   text box.

Let's call your controls `Combobox1` and `TextBox1`

> I want to take the value from the text box and store it in a string(eg
>   txt). and take the value from the combo box and store it in another
>   string(Eg combo)

Ok. Let's take their values like;

```
string combo = Combobox1.Text;
string txt = TextBox1.Text;
```

So far, so good. Let's call your column names `Column1` and `Column2` in your table. So your query should be like;

```
"select * from order where Column1='" + combo + "' AND Column2='" + txt + "'";
```

### But please don't use this way.

You should always use [`parameterized queries`](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) in your commands. It prevents, forget to use some quotes, commas etc.. But more important this kind of string concatenations are open for [`SQL Injection`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

And `order` is a *[reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)* in MySQL. You should use it with quotes.

Also use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `MySqlConnection` and `MySqlCommand`.

Here a complete example;

```
using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from `order` where Column1=@combo AND Column2=@txt";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@combo", combo); // set the combo parameter
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txt", txt); // set the txt parameter
    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            //You can read values here..
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
"select * from order where " + combo + " = '" + txt + "';";
```

Just added a space between where and combo. Does it work ?

Comment: Wrong, sql injection is not a thing to not think about

Comment: Yes of course but that's not the question here. He's talking about syntax. Maybe he already secured his vars.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to take a space between where and combo

```
"select * from order where "+combo+"='"+txt+"'";
```

that will do

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the missing space between `WHERE` and the column name, it may be you need to include the column name in backticks as well:

```
"select * from order where `" + combo + "` = '" + txt + "';";
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from SQL Injection and spacing issue in your syntax, whenever you need to construct the query where you are also injecting field names in it, we need to take care of following.

1. your combo should not accept a reserved SQL keyword. brackets can solve it but partially.
2. what if the combo field is not varchar, instead its int, then you need considerations to remove single quotes in your query.

have a look at sp_executesql, you may like it.